# Title tag is not working

Tags: html

this is my head section . i dont know why but my tittle tag is not working at all. ... visit my website www.utile.in

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="eng">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Search home professionals and design ideas</title>
    <meta name="description" content="find home remodelling contractors and design ideas" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Carpenter,Plumber,Interior designer,Architect,Electrician,Pest control,Movers and packers" />
    <meta name="author" content="metatags generator">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <meta name="revisit-after" content="1 month" />

    <!-- Interior designer,Architect,Plumber --><cmt>

    </head>
```

Comment: View the page source, you have a whole bunch of code before your actual title tag, and more excess code at the bottom.

Comment: your tittle working good on me http://i.imgur.com/34sjupZ.png

Comment: Hey thanks a lott.... bdw go through my website and suggest some improvements .... @Alexander

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the source code of your website and you will find the following in the beginning

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

you need to fix this in order to have a working title

Comment: Great to know that you fixed it

Comment: @NinadBondre : Thick as answer if this work with your problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is being inserted before your html tag, you'll need to figure out what's generating it and remove it.

```
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style_toggle.css" />

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
         <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.47/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

            $.validate();
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/searchq.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>

    </head>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <h3><a class="navbar-brand" href="home">Utile</a></h3>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Browse Photos</a></li>

            </ul>





                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="signin">Login</a></li>
                    <li><a href="signup">Sign Up</a></li>
                    <li><a href="becomemember"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Become Professional</button></a></li>
                </ul>


        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this inside the header page source.. you missed the title

```
     <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the title tag you created doesnt show up its text in the browser, you should probably try restarting your web server or clearing the browser cache and reload the file.